# Como preencher dados no input html

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou realizando a criação de um site para estudo e surgiu uma duvida, onde criei um HTML Básico com banco de dados e estou tentando passar alguns valores manualmente, mas quando aperto o botão alterar, os campos não são preenchidos automaticamente com o botão.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("button").click(function() {
    var $id_user = $("input[name='id_user']");
    var $usuario = $("input[name='usuario']");
    var $login = $("input[name='login']");
    var $senha = $("input[name='senha']"); 
    $.ajax({
    url: "alterarconfig.php?id_user=1",
    data: {id_user: 1},
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "POST",
    success: function retorna(json) {
        $usuario.val(json.usuario);
        $login.val(json.login);
        $senha.val(json.senha);
    }

 });
});  
</script>
<div class="config">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form method="POST" action="alterarconfig.php?id_user=1">
        <label>ID</label><input readonly="true" type="text" class="form-control" id="id_user" name="id_user" value="<?php $valores['usuario'] ?>"><br>
        <label>Usuário</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario" value="<?php $valores['usuario'] ?>"><br>
        <label>E-mail/Login</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" value="<?php $valores['usuario'] ?>"><br>
        <label>Senha Atual</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" value="<?php $valores['usuario'] ?>"><br>
        <label>Endereço</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end" name="end"><br>
        <label>Número</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero" name="numero"><br>
        <label>Bairro</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bairro" name="bairro"><br>
        <label>Cidade</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city"><br>
        <label>Telefone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel"><br>
        <label>Celular</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cel" name="cel"><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-roxo">Alterar</button> 
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer id="rodape">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-2">
        <span class="img-logo-footer"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-10">
        <h4>Contato</h4>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="navbar-font"><a href="">Sobre</a></li>
          <li class="navbar-font"><a href="">gh.developerapp@gmail.com</a></li>
          <li class="navbar-font"><a href="">+55(19)99219-1600</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Meu php:

```
  <?php
session_start() ;

function retorna($id_user){
    try{
        require('conexao.php') ;
        $sql = "SELECT usu.* FROM usuario usu Where usu.id = :id LIMIT 1" ;
        $stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql) ;
        $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id_user));

        $logou = 0 ;

        while($consulta = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $valores['id_user'] = $consulta["id"] ;
            $valores['usuario'] = $consulta["usuario"] ;
            $valores['login'] = $consulta["login"] ;
            $valores['senha'] = $consulta["senha"] ;

            $logou = 1 ;
        }

        if($logou = 0){
            echo "Sem resultado de usuário válido..";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo " ".$ex;
    }
    return json_encode($valores);
}
if(isset($_POST['id_user'])){
    echo retorna($_POST['id_user']);
}
?>
```

Porem, a página retorna em branco.. alguém pode me ajudar com este problema?

Comment: Você quer retornar quais dados? Não está funcionando pois a url `alterarconfig.php` precisa de um parâmetro. Ex: `alterarconfig.php?id_user=1`. Quando você atribui `method="POST"` é necessário usar `$_POST['id_user']` para capturar esse valor. Ah, e há um erro em `funcion`, o correto é `function`

Comment: Fiz as edições e trouxe os resultados, mas ainda não consegui preencher o input com o resultado do json. Gostaria de saber se existe outra forma para efetuar estas alterações ?

Comment: Não precisa desse `?id_user=1` porque ele já é enviado pelo Ajax em `{id_user: 1}`

Comment: Coloque na primeira linha do success: `console.log(json)` e nos informe o que aparece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você preencher um formulário com dados que estão em outra página, é necessário utilizar `jQuery.ajax` ou `XMLHttpRequest` *(JS Puro)*.

Primeiro você precisa substituir o atributo `type="submit"` para `type="button"` e remover o atributo `action` do botão *Alterar*.

O atributo `type="submit"` vai te redirecionar para outra página e, pelo visto, não é isso que queres.

Após essa alteração basta utilizar o código abaixo para requisitar os dados do usuário.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "alterarconfig.php?id_user=1",
        data: {id_user: 1},
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(json) {
            $usuario.val(json.usuario);
            $login.val(json.login);
            $senha.val(json.senha);
        }

    });
});
```

---

Outra forma é adicionar o código `php` em sua `view`, ou código `html`. Dessa forma você poderá adicionar o atributo `value` com o valor capturado pelo `php`. Ex:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php $valores['usuario'] ?>" />
```

---

Segue exemplo completo do teste que fiz.

**alterarconfig.php**

```
<?php
session_start() ;

function retorna($id_user){

    $valores = [];

    try{
        $conexao = new PDO("mysql:dbname=teste;host=localhost:3307", "root", "123456");

        $sql = "SELECT usu.* FROM usuario usu Where usu.id = :id LIMIT 1" ;
        $stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql) ;
        $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id_user));

        while($consulta = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $valores['id_user'] = $consulta["id"] ;
            $valores['usuario'] = $consulta["usuario"] ;
            $valores['login'] = $consulta["login"] ;
            $valores['senha'] = $consulta["senha"] ;
        }

        if (empty($valores)) {
            throw new PDOException("Nenhum valor foi encontrado.");
        }

    } catch(PDOException $ex){
        $valores["error"] = utf8_decode($ex->getMessage());
    }

    return json_encode($valores);
}

if(isset($_POST['id_user'])){
    echo retorna($_POST['id_user']);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="wait" style="display:none">Aguarde...</div>

        <form method="POST" action="alterarconfig.php?id_user=1">
            <label>ID</label><input readonly="true" type="text" class="form-control" id="id_user" name="id_user" value="1"><br>
            <label>Usuário</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario" value=""><br>
            <label>E-mail/Login</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" value=""><br>
            <label>Senha Atual</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" value=""><br>
            <label>Endereço</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end" name="end"><br>
            <label>Número</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero" name="numero"><br>
            <label>Bairro</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bairro" name="bairro"><br>
            <label>Cidade</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city"><br>
            <label>Telefone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel"><br>
            <label>Celular</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cel" name="cel"><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-roxo">Alterar</button> 
        </form>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("button").click(function() {
                var id_user = $("input[name='id_user']");
                var usuario = $("input[name='usuario']");
                var login = $("input[name='login']");
                var senha = $("input[name='senha']"); 

                $.ajax({
                    url: "alterarconfig.php?id_user=1",
                    data: {id_user: $(id_user).val()},
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    type: "POST",
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $(".wait").show();
                    },
                    success: function retorna(json) {
                        if (json.error) {
                            alert(json.error);
                            return;
                        }

                        usuario.val(json.usuario);
                        login.val(json.login);
                        senha.val(json.senha);
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $(".wait").hide();
                    }
                });
            });  
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adicionei ambos arquivos na mesma pasta.

Comment: Obrigado pelo auxilio, ele não redirecionou de página como informou, mas ainda não trouxe nenhum valor nos campos previamente ditos. Alterei a pergunta para voce ver como alterei o código.

Comment: @GabrielHenrique adicionei um exemplo mais completo. Não utilizei conexão com banco de dados por se tratar apenas de um teste simples. Você verificou se a página está, realmente, retornando os dados?

Comment: realmente não está atualizando a página, mas a pagina alterarconfig.php retorna os valores normalmente, mas o input não recebe os dados.

Comment: @GabrielHenrique Adicionei um código completo. Antes de clicar no botão "Alterar" pressione F12 e observe a requisição na aba "Network". O código está bem simples e essas partes irei deixar para você refatorar posteriormente. Ps.: Não se esqueça de adaptar os dados de conexão com o banco de dados.

Comment: Amigo, o seu html funcionou perfeitamente, sem que eu alterasse nada no alterarconfig.php.. Irei refazer a pagina e ver o que estava causando conflito de atualização e apresentação do dados.

Comment: Descobri!! Existia outras scripts que invalidavam a execução do botão, funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado a todos!